# How to delete each row having all columns is equal to None for a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, null, data-cleaning

For example
   [data frame example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kby7n.png)
I want to delete each row which are having all columns = NA. I don't want to delete rows which are not having NAs in all columns. Kindly give some suggestions with examples. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Try `df.dropna(how='all', inplace=True)`

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
df.dropna(how='all', inplace=True)
```

From [documentation (pandas.DataFrame.dropna)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

> how : {‘any’, ‘all’}, default ‘any’
>
> > Determine if row or column is removed from DataFrame, when we have at least one NA or all NA.
> >
> > ‘any’ : If any NA values are present, drop that row or column.
> >
> > ‘all’ : If all values are NA, drop that row or column.

and `inplace`:

> inplace : bool, default False
>
> > If True, do operation inplace and return None.

Answer (score 1):

youre looking for pd.dropna(axis=0,thresh=3)

if you set thresh = to the number of columns you have itll only drop rows with everything nan.

[docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

edit: i misread how=all, students comment is probably a better anwser

Comment: Thanks. But I want to delete rows having identical column values. Here values are NA. Kindly give example on that. I don't want to drop NA for rows having one or two columns = NAs

Comment: Thanks a lot. The dropna documentation is very helpful.

Comment: for claritys sake, a row that is [1,1,1] would also need be dropped?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the column names in `dropna` as:

`df.dropna(subset = ['column1_name', 'column2_name', 'column3_name'])`

This will remove the NA values.